# How to add a value at the end of a Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to add a value to end of a dictionary that is formatted with `[String : Int]`. Usually, I could just use the `dict[5] = "example"` but since it is formatted with `[String : Int]` I am unable to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered. They don't have an "end"

Comment: Angela speaks truth. Dictionaries are unordered, so there is no end to them. She should post this as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to add ordered values you need to use an array:

```
var dict:[String] = []
```

You can then append items to it using

```
dict.append("example")
```

Your line:

```
dict[5] = "example"
```

will change the item at index 5 and will set it to be "example". However, if your array contains less items it will crash as it will not be able to access such index. So, either add your items when you initialise an array:

```
var dict:[String] = ["example1","example2"]
```

or use `append()`